# how do I get the final value out of this function?

Tags: python, function, loops

So I have coded a game of snakes and ladders. However, instead of doing it so that it takes it in turns between players, I've made it so that it runs one player all the way through the game and records how many turns it took them to finish. then it runs player two all the way through and records how many turns it took them. at the end, it then compares the final scores of each player and the lowest score wins (since it took them less turns to reach the end). I know this isn't the best set up for this game but its what I'm going with lol.

However, I just need help with getting the final_score value out of this function. when the player has passed `100`, it successfully does the else bit and shows their total number of turns it took them to finish. this `total_rolls` value in that last bit of the function is what I need to pull out. so I tried assigning it to `final_score` and then asking it to return `final_score`.

however, when I do this, it says the output is none.

```py
import random 
def roll_dice():
    dice_value = random.randint(1,6)
    print("its a... " + str(dice_value)
    return dice_value 

def move_player(player, current_pos, total_rolls):
    snake_squares = {26: 17, 40: 9, 43: 24, 67: 25, 75: 57, 82: 71, 98: 80} #the squares with snakes on
    ladder_squares = {10: 40, 16: 38, 37: 46, 41: 52, 50: 68, 53: 73, 87: 97} #the squares with ladders on 
    print("Your turn, " + str(player))
    input(str(player) + " , type 'roll' to roll the dice" + "\n")
    obtained_dice = roll_dice()
    new_pos = current_pos + obtained_dice 
    print(str(player) + ", move to space " + str(new_pos)) 
    total_rolls = total_rolls 
    total_rolls += 1 #counts how many turns the player has taken 
    print("number of rolls:" + str(total_rolls))
    
 
    while new_pos < 100:
        if new_pos in snake_squares: #if they land on a snake
            print("Oh no! you have landed on a snake!" + "\n" + "You fall down the snake and land back on square {0}". format(snake_squares[new_pos]))
            new_pos = snake_squares[new_pos]
            move_player(player_one, new_pos, total_rolls)
                  
        elif new_pos in ladder_squares: #if they land on a ladder
            print("Hurray, you have landed on a ladder!" + "\n" + "Climb the ladder and move to square number {0}". format(ladder_squares[new_pos]))
            new_pos = ladder_squares[new_pos]
            move_player(player_one, new_pos, total_rolls)
            
        else: #if they land on a normal square
            move_player(player_one, new_pos, total_rolls)
            
    #if they pass 100 and finish 
    print("It took " + str(player_one) + " " + str(total_rolls) + " rolls of the dice to reach the top of the board ")
    print(total_rolls) 
    return total_rolls
        

p1_final_score = move_player(player_one, 1, 1)
print(p1_final_score)
```

so I've changed the loop to a while loop I think and it still doesn't seem to return what I need.

output when it reaches 100 and ends the while loop looks like this:

tara, move to space 100

number of rolls:23

It took tara 23 rolls of the dice to reach the top of the board

23

2

why does it successfully retain the roll count for the statements I've printed but not when I try and return the value?

Comment: looks like you only return in the else

Comment: Are you certain the `else` is ever reached? Is `new_pos  < 100` every really false? Maybe the function is doing to many iterations before it fails? Without knowing what `player` does, or how you call the function, it's very hard

Comment: should I return total_rolls in each of the ifs?

Comment: @MitchellvanZuylen I've just added two lines at the bottom to show how im calling it and trying to get the final value to print.

Comment: Can you add the roll_dice function?

Comment: @MitchellvanZuylen added the roll_dice function now :)

Comment: also tried adding return total_rolls to the bottom of each if and now it returns a value but it returns 2 as final_score, not the total number of rolls. so it will successfully say something like "it took player one 31 rolls of the dice to reach the end of the board", but then the final_score value still comes out as 2

Comment: If you apply the while loop, you should no longer make repeated function calls. Most of what no happens in your function can move inside the while loop. As you can see in my answer, the while loop doesn't use any repeated function calls

Answer (score 1):

As YHF points out using a while loop might be easier here. However, it is possible with recursive functions (which is what you are doing here)

Let's see what your code does, to find the error:
You call the function `move_player` once and try to get it's output. On that first iteration, the `if` statement is true, so it does not reach the return, and thus it returns none. Inside that `if` statement, the function is called again and again until the `if` is false and therefor the function returns something. However, the value returned in that iteration is lost, because it is not stored anywhere within the `if` statement.

We can solve this with a while loop. Inside a `while new_pos  < 100` we can keep changing the position, and then the number of iterations in the while loop represents the number of turns.

```
def move_player(player):
    position = 1 # start position
    total_rolls = 1 # first turn
    while position < 100:
         # a new turn
         total_rolls = total_rolls  + 1
         position = position + 25 
    # when we reach this, the while statement is no longer true
    return total_rolls
```

With recursive this would work. Note that I removed a lot of functionality to highlight only the turns. You would have to add the functionality again, but that should be simple.

```
def move_player(player, current_pos, total_rolls):
    new_pos = current_pos + dice_roll()
    total_rolls += 1 #counts how many turns the player has taken 
    if new_pos < 100:
        total_rolls = move_player(player_one, new_pos, total_rolls)
    return total_rolls
```

This function is called once by you, let's call this 'function call zero'. Then `total_rolls` is set to 1. Then, as the if resolves to false, we call the function again. Then total_rolls is set to 2 and we call it again, and again and again until finally. The return in `function call zero` will not be executed until all the iterations are completed. That is, each inner function call needs to be finished before the outer/functional call zero is finished

Comment: thanks so much. im still a little bit confused tho (im a proper newbie sorry haha)

Comment: why do you add 25 to position?

Comment: omg I think I understand it now! just added the total_rolls = move_player(player_one, new_pos, total_rolls) to the end of the if branches and it works! thank you so so much!

Comment: The +25 is just to speed it up and not have to type 'roll'

Answer (score 0):

I thinks you need a while loop, not using recursive.